# using sys root for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' warning in NPM install

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm, react-native-ios

For some reason I'm not able to do NPM install on my project anymore since I'm getting the following messages:

```
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: building for macOS, but linking in .tbd file (/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib) built for iOS Simulator
ld: warning: bui
```

How to fix this???? I have tried uninstalling node and reinstalling node but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I don't know, where the issue comes from but after **logging out** and **restarting**, everything got back on track.

Answer (score 3):

After spending a few hours debugging this particular error (though in a different context) I have found that I had pointed the `SDKROOT` environment variable to the iOS SDK, which caused Clang to use that as a sysroot. **Unsetting `SDKROOT` solved the issue for me.**

Side note: That also explains why logging out and restarting works - as a way of clearing all temporarily set environment variables.

Comment: This solved it for me for `@parcel/watcher` package.